# Throttling Internet speed to device or vlan

Tags: vlan, qos, bandwidth

I have a Netgear FVS318N Firewall/Router, GS752TP Switch, and a Netgear WNAP210 AP. After a bit of searching, I have identified a machine that is using the lion's share of bandwidth (youtube).

Is it possible to limit bandwidth rates on a device basis using the hardware I have, or alternatively, for a particular VLAN?

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question. For example, you say "using the lion's share of bandwidth" but don't mention where this bottleneck is occurring (i.e. Internet, wireless, elsewhere?).

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the manual, [CLI Manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/FVS318N/FVS318N_CLI.pdf), starting on page 148:

> **Bandwidth Profile Commands**
>
> **security bandwidth profile add**
>
> This command configures a new bandwidth profile. After you have issued
>   the `security bandwidth profile add command`, you enter the
>   security-config [bandwidth-profile] mode, and then you can configure
>   one keyword and associated parameter or associated keyword at a time
>   in the order that you prefer